# PHP Simple HTML DOM - How to get the text inside a tag

Tags: php, html, dom

I use PHP Simple HTML Dom to get some HTML, now I have a HTML dom like follow code, I need fetch the plain text inner a tag, but I am getting the text link([Kiwi Fruit Basket](http://floristchennai.com/kiwi-basket)).

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="name" style="height: 34px;">
    <a href="http://floristchennai.com/kiwi-basket">Kiwi Fruit Basket</a>
</div>
```

**Php Code**

```
 // Create DOM from URL or file
 $html = file_get_html('http://floristchennai.com/');

 // Find all links text
 foreach($html->find('.name a') as $element) 
 {
    echo "<br>a tag text value=" . $element;
 }
```

Doing it this way I don't get the text I want to get.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:
`innertext()` innertext used for Read or write the inner HTML text of element.

```
    foreach($html->find('.name a') as $element) 
    {
        echo "<br>a tag text value=" . $element->innertext;
    }
```

[API Ref](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm)