# PHP Web Scraping: Im getting the whole tag instead of its content

Tags: php, dom, web-scraping

im new to Web Scraping. Im trying to retrieve a number("18.7696") from a td tag in a website. Im using [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) and the line that gets the number is:

```
$td= $html->find("td[class=txt]");
$number= $td[3];
```

However Im getting the whole tag with its attributes: `<td width="52%" align="center" class="txt">18.7696...`

Is this achievable using only the HTML DOM Parser or do I have to use a regex?

Comment: What about `$number= $td[3]->innertext;` See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36371343/2146113

Comment: Yup. That worked. Thanks Robin.